# Querying by date in mongo db

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, jongo

I am new to Mongodb. I want to find those objects stored in mongodb whose `receivedOn` date is greater than a particular date. My object structure is :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("591313fa79a7f2826cdfcdbd"),
    "uuid" : "849cf178-bf19-4a32-bda8-b754551c57f0",
    "status" : "SENT",
    "receivedOn" : ISODate("2017-05-10T18:51:58.893+05:30"),
    "scheduledOn" : ISODate("2017-05-10T18:51:58.893+05:30"),
    "deliveredOn" : ISODate("2017-05-10T18:52:02.628+05:30")
}
```

I am using Jongo driver for querying. My query looks like:

```
collection.find("{\"receivedOn\": {$gte : #}}", javaDate);
```

I am getting no results from this query but there are documents in collection which should have been returned. What's wrong with my query?

Comment: what is javaDate? java.util.Date or jodatime?

Comment: It is java.util.Date

Answer (score 0):

```
db.CollectionName.find({"receivedOn" : new ISODate("2017-05-10T18:51:58.893+05:30") });
```

Comment: how does that get 'greater than'?

Comment: I am getting JsonParserException in java. but it works in mono shell.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using java,util.Date, there could be timezone issues when Date object is converted to json. Java might be adding/subtracting hours to your date based on timezone. Ideally while storing dates, they should be in  UTC format, and while retrieving, they should be in UTC.

Comment: Even if I use same timezone, I am not getting result. Is there something with my query? If i query using ISODate in mongo shell , I get correct resuts. Is mongo date type compatible with java.util.Date?

Comment: How are you ensuring that it is same time zone? can you please post more code around it?